# Apache not working on my Mac with Sierra

Tags: macos, apache

I've followed instruction on how to activate Apache on my Mac prior to upgrading to Sierra. I got the "It Works" page after entering localhost in the address field, yet after I upgraded to Sierra, I got the "This site cannot be reached" page.

All of my (Google) searches say to to deactivate Apache with this:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

but, when I use that, this is returned:

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service
```

I have tried:

```
sudo achapectl stop,
```

but receive:

```
sudo: achapectl: command not found
```

Can someone help!?

Comment: the command is `apachectl` not achapectl

Comment: I was encountering the same issue when trying to unload with `launchctl` and `/usr/sbin/httpd -k stop` wasn't helping either as it would automatically restart immediately. Unable to find what was starting it, I purposefully put a syntax error in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and used `kill` to stop the running process. Certainly not an elegant solution, but I was under a time crunch and didn't have the freedom to track down at the time what the root cause of apache restarting itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to (force-)unload a system daemon or agent which isn't actually loaded or running you will get the displayed error:

> ...: Could not find specified service

So first check if the daemon is running (example Apache):

```
sudo launchctl list | grep apache
```

If it's running unload it:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

---

As mentioned by the user Gio Valerio, the proper command to start/stop Apache is:

```
sudo apachectl start|stop
```

Comment: should be `sudo launchctl list | grep apache` make sure you're not making a typo, otherwise it will always be `command not found`